# create directory for aidl file

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-purchase

I am doing the in-app billing example on https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample
In the section "Add the In-app Billing Library to existing app" it says

"In Android Studio: Create a directory named aidl under src/main, add a new package com.android.vending.billing in this directory, and import the IInAppBillingService.aidl file into this package."

My problem is that in "android view" i can not create directory. When i change view to "project view" I can create the directory, but not the package. And when I create the directory in "project view" and change back to "android view" to create the package, the directory I created in "project view" is not visible?

I have tried just adding as a package, but then I can not get the import to work?

I am sure it is a tiny thing I have overlooked - please help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your default system file explorer. Navigate to the src/main folder of your project and create the following folders.

- create folder `aidl`
- inside the `aidl` folder: create folder `com`
- inside the `aidl/com` folder: create folder `android`
- inside the `aidl/com/android` folder: create folder `vending`
- inside the `aidl/com/android/vending` folder: create folder `billing`

Then paste the `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file inside your billing folder. Back to Android Studio and you will use the package with the file using the "Android" view.

Comment: Hi 
Thx for your answer :-) I worked with a combination.

I ended up creating the folders in my file explorer and then I could see them in "android view" 
But it would not recognize them as a package, so i deleted the com/android/vending/Billing  and added a package to the folder i created through file explorer

Comment: And you get the answer for pointing towards the file explorer - thx :-)